# White booklet that lists key pieces in Ramban Al HaTorah?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, ramban

I was told there's a small white booklet which lists the main pieces in Ramban Al HaTorah for each parsha. I have asked around and people have told me that it has been out of print for a while.

1. Does anyone know the official name of this sefer?
2. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC its from a Rabbi Yerachmiel Fried from Dallas - maybe try to contact him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s called ציונים לענינים באמונה ויסודות הדת בפירוש הרמב״ן עה״ת.

[image]

As pointed out by רבות מחשבות in a comment, the author is R. Yerachmiel David Fried.

Around ten years ago it was available in all the Jerusalem Hebrew bookstores - I have no idea if that is still the case.

I have a copy at home if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 6):

The book is available for purchase as a PDF from Otzar Hachochmah https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?85409&