# Select Ohr HaChaim list?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation

In yeshiva, guys who learned Ramban al HaTorah used to use [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95029/2699) list that contained the "must-see" Ramban's on that week's parsha.

Is there an equivalent list of Ohr HaChaim's?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... I'll try to ask around, but I doubt it exists.

Comment: http://rashi541820.blogspot.com/2016/11/blog-post_38.html?m=1