# Learning Ramban Al HaTorah

Tags: product-recommendation, ramban

I'd like to begin learning Ramban Al HaTorah and was wondering if someone has had experience with learning Ramban using a certain set of Chumash. I know of three different sets that have *biurim*/notes and was wondering what the differences are between them and which anyone has found to be the most helpful.

The sets are [this](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F---%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94---%D7%A1%D7%98---%D7%94%22%D7%9B---%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9), [this](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8---%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%96-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8---%D7%99%22%D7%9B), and [this](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F---%D7%91%22%D7%9B---%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95027/759

Comment: I'm not sure whether you know already, but the third set you linked to has only the Ramban and not the text of the Torah

Answer (score 8):

I have learned Ramban al Hatorah with a chavrusa this year. I used the third set you linked (Chavel Ramban, Mossad Harav Kook), and my chavrusa used the first one, the Tuv Yerushalaim set. Tuv Yerushalaim had commentary that was slightly easier to understand, but also skips commenting on any sections that are Kabbalah-heavy. If that's not a focus for you, I would recommend the Tuv Yerushalaim for a beginner. I have no experience with the second set, the Oz Vehadar, but if it's anything like their commentary in their Mikraos Gedolos, it will be extremely comprehensive.

A few other notes:

1. mbloch, in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105852/11501) answer, noted Rabbi Yerachmiel Fried's [list of important Rambans](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95027/white-booklet-that-lists-key-pieces-in-ramban-al-hatorah). I found it quite useful (although I didn't get it from mbloch), as he titles the pieces with short summaries.
2. I would not recommend learning Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechayei alongside Ramban, as he is an independent commentary, and often even harder to understand. If you wanted to learn a relevant commentary, I would suggest Rashi or Ibn Ezra, what the Ramban often quotes and disagrees with. Alternatively, you can learn the full commentary of the Tur, which he himself says is based on the Ramban, and may serve to help explain the Ramban in a few sections.

Comment: @mbloch please see the linked question

Comment: Yes, I was the one to put in the link :-> I wrote my answer, then realized DoubleAA had pointed to that question, and deleted my answer. I then edited yours to provide the link and upvoted :->

Comment: Do you know if any sets of Ramban help explain those parts al pi Kabbalah?

Comment: I would assume the other two have notes on it. Also, the chevel English translation, IIRC, contains them and would help. Another options is to consult those rishonim who discuss Ramban's Kabbalah routinely, perhaps Tziuni, maybe R' Bachya, and there's a couple of others I'm forgetting.

Comment: @mbloch was your chavrusah using the newly printed edition of the Tuv Yerushalayim set or the older one?

Comment: @Bochur613 inn my case an older one for sure - he told me he learned it first 17 years ago - but I think you want to ask רבות מחשבות

Comment: @bochur seemed pretty new to me...

Answer (score 3):

This is really more of an opinion-style question and may end up getting closed as off-topic.

But if your objective is to understand what Ramban teaches, any one of the newer, complete and accurate texts is good. My preference is the Rav Kook edition which you linked to.

In general, when learning Ramban to the Torah and especially over Bereshit, it is a good practice to learn side-by-side for contrast and comparison, [Rabbeinu Bahya ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher). Rabbeinu Bahya was a student of the Rashba, who was a student of the Ramban. So the context is appropriate. There is also a Mossad HaRav Kook edition for that too.

And if you are looking for any additional clarification, include the super commentary, [HaEzrach B'Yisrael by Rabbi Yisroel Yitzchok Koronet](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/31205) which clarifies Rabbeinu Bahya.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wonderful initiative. I am doing this as well, using artscroll's [7-volume elucidation](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/RBNSET.html). Since you are mentioning 3 Hebrew-only *chumashim*, you might not want English.

But I have something else which might prove very beneficial to make the task more manageable in a first pass. There is a list of the most important Ramban al ha Torah commentaries which someone has compiled (I uploaded it [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/419499702/Ramban-key-comments-from-his-Torah-commentary?secret_password=FhXRB2T5ZWfj5V8U48DP)), sorted by *parasha*, with a short index on the last page.

PS. Unfortunately I do not know who the author is. There is no copyright information I found either.

[image]