# Is there a list of important sugyos in the mishneh Torah

Tags: lomdus, mishneh-torah

I heard Rav Lichtenstein made a list of important sugyos in the mishneh Torah to learn. Does anyone have it or something similar?

Comment: What are "sugyos in the mishneh Torah"?

Comment: @Richard Franklin   I wonder how you classify 'important', what part of torah is 'unimportant'.

Comment: @interested there are similar lists for Ramban's commentary on the Torah, see for instance https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105858/11501

Comment: @mbloch I would rather you just told me what is considered unimportant, one example will do.

Comment: @interested if you have to prioritize, then Hilchot Sotah, Klei hamikdash, Temura, Para Aduma, Avadim or Mamrim are not yet relevant nowadays. Entire bodies of Halacha were written without touching these topics (SA, MB, etc)

Comment: @mbloch Thats better. So you are saying what is not relevant nowadays is not considered 'important'. Although that is not the word I would have used. I shouldnt think that is difficult at all.

Comment: @interested I didn’t say it wasn’t important. But it is of lesser priority. Personally I learned all of Mishne Torah but fully accept that not everyone wants to learn halachot which don’t yet apply. I’m also learning of all Ramban and am using the priority list I linked to above to make it less overwhelming

Comment: @mbloch I was referring to the one who asked the question who did use the word important. I have a feeling he doesnt mean the same as you. I may add that the MB made up for it and included 'everything' in his other works.