# Looking for a sefer with a collection of interesting/fundamental Rishonim on the Parsha

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rishonim

I'm looking for a sefer which is a collection of interesting, original and fundamental pieces from the Rishonim on the weekly Parsha. I prefer if they are quotes [the original wording], but also happy if they paraphrase what the Rishonim write.

Any recommendations?

Comment: https://www.kodeshbook.co.il/product.asp?productid=3751

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95027/759

Comment: Mikraos Gedolos? Mossad Harav Kook Toras Chaim?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm looking for a selection of the interesting/fundamental pieces, rather than the entire collection of Rishonic works. There is too much for me to go through weekly; I'm looking for someone who has done the work and highlighted interesting/important pieces.

Comment: ArtScroll Stone Chumash (though this includes Aharonim too)

Comment: Nechama Leibowitz does this

Comment: The book of Rav Menachem casher

Comment: @kouty that's Chazal not Rishonim

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is [Yesodei HaTorah](https://www.eshelpublications.com/store/p3/Yesodei_Hatorah_2_Volume_Set.html), which is a compilation by [Rav Ahron Lopiansky](http://ravlopiansky.com/) of the words of the Rishonim which he feels are fundamental to our faith, organized by the parsha.

You can see the first 150 pages of Volume 1 (Bereishis, Shemos) [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=172229&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=0) and Volume 2 (Vayikra, Bamidbar, Devarim) [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=172230&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=0).

Answer (score 2):

One such work is [Moshav Zekeinim al Hatorah](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/20791). It has a collection of commentaries of the Tosafists and other Rishonim on the Torah by R. Solomon David Sassoon (1915–1985).