# List of "most important" Rashis on the Torah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, rashi

There is a list of the most fundamental Ramban al ha Torah commentaries which someone has compiled (I uploaded it [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/419499702/Ramban-key-comments-from-his-Torah-commentary?secret_password=FhXRB2T5ZWfj5V8U48DP)), sorted by parasha, with a short index on the last page.

**Does something similar exist for Rashi's Torah commentary?** It would be helpful to someone able to dedicate a few hours a week to learn Rashi in-depth, but without the time to do it on all Rashis.

I realize defining the "most important" Rashis is difficult, it might be e.g., the more fundamental ones, the most often quoted, the most learned. If someone prepared such a list, I'd be interested to look at it and review whether it fits the need.

Comment: isn't this something rather subjective?

Comment: What criteria do you use for “importance”

Comment: Most learned? Most important etc..?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95029/603 — the publication was shared here as well. It includes the cover page, and you can see it is not a list of the most important ramban’s. Rather it is a list of his commentaries that talk about faith in G-d and fundamentals of Judaism. I would recommend editing your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Menachem all right, I'll call it the more fundamental Rambans - thanks

Comment: @MosesSupposes it is, but if the list exists, it has value on its own, and we can look at it to judge if relevant. If it doesn't exist then my own criteria for such a list are irrelevant. I'm not suggesting someone builds a list to answer the question

Comment: @KirkBellard see previous comment

Comment: @Shmuel you are right and I edited the question to be a bit more precise

Comment: In my opinion, the most important Rashi's are a subset of all his comments on grammar. When he is referring to Peshat, he means according to what is understood from the grammar. Are you familiar with, "An Introduction to Rashi's Grammatical Explanations" by Dr.Sampson Isserhoff?  That might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: https://jewishlink.news/dr-shimshon-isseroff-z-l-a-champion-of-talmud-torah/